# Average Margin of Error

Tags: average-precision

Sampling 100 random respondents for a binary true/false response from a total population of 220,000,000 yields a margin of error of 9.8%.

If a new random sample of 100 respondents from the same population is surveyed each day for 90 days (each day's results having a 9.8% margin of error) and the 90 daily results are then averaged, how to calculate the margin of error associated with the 90 day average?

To be clear:
tn = % true day n
90 day average = (t1+t2+...+t90) / 90

Thank you

Comment: It is astronomically unlikely that all samples will have 9.8% MoEs, because that implies they all have the same results (to two significant figures).

Comment: Margin of error refers to likelihood sample represents population.  Of course some samples may be more representative than others, but the probability that each sample is representative is the same for each sample.  Indeed, MOE can be calculated very readily given the two variables (population size, sample size) and for the population and sample given the MOE is 9.8% for each of the 90 days.

Comment: That comment does not correctly characterize what is usually meant by MoE.  In your case, because the MoE is *estimated* from the data and is *directly related* to the true/false counts, random variation in samples of size 100 will cause your estimates to vary, too.  That's why I find the assumptions in this question to be so strange and unrealistic.

Comment: Is there a way to "bump" the question to get more visibility?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/asking